# Tag synonym request: painting and paint

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[paint](/questions/tagged/paint) should become a synonym of [painting](/questions/tagged/painting). They currently have matching tag wikis, and should be synonymized.

I don't have the 'expertise' in painting to do this myself.